# How can I install Itop on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, apache2, localhost

Recently I tried to install ITop on my xubuntu but all of my tries were unsuccessful. I used a lot of links like http://www.unixmen.com/setup-operational-portal-using-itop-centosdebian/ and the official page as well, I installed apache and it works but when I type `localhost/itop` it raises the following error :

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /itop/ on this server.
```

does anybody had such experience with Itop?

Comment: I think you should include the probable "403" code you probably received with the error because of the confusion. Otherwise, this looks like kind of like the sort of error you would get when you need to use sudo.

Comment: @mchid I thought so but I typed `localhost/itop` on browser, how can I use sudo in this case?

Comment: You can't, that's what I am saying. I believe other people might think the error is in the terminal, however, I think you probably just have to set the correct permissions for localhost as described here for that directory https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/httpd.html#http-configuration

Comment: @mchid the result of `ls -l` shows the following permission for itop folder `drwxrwxrwx`

Comment: no, I think you need to set the *apache* permissions like in this example except, I don't think you would want to allow access to all as described but this should point you in the right direction http://askubuntu.com/questions/413887/403-forbidden-after-changing-documentroot-directory-apache-2-4-6?lq=1

Comment: @mchid Check my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure it out. The problem was because of the root path in file `000-default.conf` at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory`.

If we lunch this file in terminal we'll see the following result:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

...
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see in line `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`  the `DocumentRoot` has been set to `/var/www/html` which it should be set on following address :

```
/var/www/itop
```

and in file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/itop

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

...
</VirtualHost>
```